# No renderer for this activity - Microsoft Bot Framework Emulator qnamaker

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, azure-qna-maker, npm-start

When I run the qnamaker chatbot, I get this message on the emulator along with the answers when I type a question.

```
{
    "type":"trace"
    "serviceUrl":"http://localhost:port#"
    "channelId": "emulator"
    etc
}
```

Is this an error. If not, how can I hide it from showing on the emulator chat window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this isn't an error - the log level is trace.
From your config you must select the verbosity of the logging to exclude the log level trace.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I upgraded the emulator from version 4.3.0 to 4.3.2. It does not show the QnAMaker trace on the chat window now.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade the emulator to latest version to 4.3.2.You can get it from here https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases/tag/v4.3.2